# How can I remove excess commercial flooring tile adhesive?

Tags: flooring, cleaning, adhesive

I just covered the floor of my small indoor storage room with Armstrong commercial flooring tiles.  I used the proper adhesive for the application that I got in the same department at the big box store as the tiles.  Unfortunately, I messed up a little and some adhesive got squeezed up through the joints when I was setting the tiles, which I tried to wipe with a wet paper towel but did not succeed entirely.

So now, when I walk, my shoes stick to the tiles.  I wonder if there is some cleaning solution that I can use to remove the tacky goo, but that won't leak through the joints and weaken the tiles grip on the floor.

Answer (score 2):

Does the container for the adhesive suggest anything for cleanup? Maybe mineral spirits or acetone? Be careful with those on your tiles though. Maybe "goof off" would work.

Comment: actually someone else told me mineral spirits and that worked well.  i suppose mineral spirits are the way to go for all adhesive cleanup (i wonder if they work with contact cement)

Comment: Mineral spirits worked wonderfully.